# Convert a list of files to a tree-like dictionary

Tags: python

Suppose I have a list that looks like this:

```
list_all_files = [['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file1'], 
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file3'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file4'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder2', 'file1'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder2', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder1', 'file1'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder3', 'file1'],
                  ['folder3', 'file2'],
                  ['folder4', 'subfolder1', 'file1'],
                  ['folder4', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file1'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file3'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file4']]
```

"list_all_files" is just an example - the list could also have zero or n folders and/or subfolders and/or files. How can I convert it to a dictionary that looks like the following?

```
dict_all_files =

{    'folder1': {'subfolder1': {'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'},
                 'subfolder2': {'file1', 'file2'}},
     'folder2': {'subfolder1': {'file1', 'file2'},
                 'subfolder2': {'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'}},
     'folder3': {'file1', 'file2'},
     'folder4': {'subfolder1': {'file1', 'file2'}}    }
```

I tried looping over the list and using dict.update(), starting like this:

```
dict_all_files = {}
for member in list_all_files:
    if member[0] == 'folder1':
        dict_all_files.update({'folder1': ''})
        for element in member:
            if member[1] == 'subfolder1':
                dict_all_files.update({folder1': member[1]})
```

But then I would overwrite folders and also I would have to write if statements for every folder and subfolder manually, which wouldn't be very practical. So it makes no sense working on my code because it is already flawed. Perhaps I'm thinking wrong from the start? Would be nice if anyone could provide an answer or at least a hint. I haven't found any questions answering this or a similar question.

Comment: So each list will always end with a file?

Comment: with the name of a file, yes

Comment: `{'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'}` -- is this a set?

Comment: @ggorlen: yes it is

Comment: How do you generate `list_all_files`? Why not generate `dict_all_files` directly?

Comment: @DeepSpace: I'm using the audio_metadata library to access metadata (like artist, title and album) of each filepath. I want artist to be the folder and (if it exists) album to be the subfolder containing all the titles. I'm generating the list by looping over the list of all filepaths, thus generating a list [artist, album, title] for each filepath and comprising all those sublists in "list_all_files".

Comment: What would happen in case of no folder or subfoler? Ex : just `[file1]`.

Comment: I don't think this data structure makes a lot of sense. What is supposed to happen if you have a folder that contains a mix of files and subfolders? In this case, it's inappropriate to use a set, but if you do use a dict, then you have leaf nodes with unclear attributes. I recommend a redesign to take this into account. A simple example that seems perfectly valid but breaks your format is is `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'x', 'c']]`. `b` is clearly a file, but we can't make `a` a set because `x` is a folder.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dict.setdefault` to clean your code.

```
import pprint
list_all_files = [['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file1'], 
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file3'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file4'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder2', 'file1'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder2', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder1', 'file1'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder3', 'file1'],
                  ['folder3', 'file2'],
                  ['folder4', 'subfolder1', 'file1'],
                  ['folder4', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file1'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file3'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file4']]

result = {}
for path in list_all_files:
    head = result
    for name in path[:-2]:
        head = head.setdefault(name,{})
    head.setdefault(path[-2],set()).add(path[-1])

pprint.pprint(result)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{'folder1': {'subfolder1': set(['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4']),
             'subfolder2': set(['file1', 'file2'])},
 'folder2': {'subfolder1': set(['file1', 'file2']),
             'subfolder2': set(['file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'])},
 'folder3': set(['file1', 'file2']),
 'folder4': {'subfolder1': set(['file1', 'file2'])}}
```

Comment: Super awesome code, but unfortunately this fails on input like `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'x', 'c']]`.

Comment: @ggorlen the expected output cannot be a dict for your input. A tree data structure like a 
 trie would be better.

Comment: Yeah, I think the data structure needs attention--supporting mixed files and folders in a directory should be supported, I would imagine. This gives OP what they want but I think it's an xy problem.

Comment: @ggorlen Since he specifically says tree like dictionary. I am not quite sure what he meant.

Answer (score 2):

```py
list_all_files = [['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file1'], 
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file3'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder1', 'file4'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder2', 'file1'],
                  ['folder1', 'subfolder2', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder1', 'file1'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder3', 'file1'],
                  ['folder3', 'file2'],
                  ['folder4', 'subfolder1', 'file1'],
                  ['folder4', 'subfolder1', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file1'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file2'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file3'],
                  ['folder2', 'subfolder2', 'file4']]

tree = dict()
def create_tree(l):
    for f in l:
        cur = tree
        # all folders and subfolder till will have dict as key except last subfolder/folder.
        for s in f[:-2]:
            if s not in cur:
                cur[s] = dict()
            cur = cur[s]

        # last folder/subfolder will be list.
        if f[-2] not in cur:
            cur[f[-2]] = set()
        cur = cur[f[-2]]

        # add file to list
        cur.add(f[-1])

create_tree(list_all_files)
tree
```

- Output:

```
{'folder1': {'subfolder1': {'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'},
             'subfolder2': {'file1', 'file2'}},
 'folder2': {'subfolder1': {'file1', 'file2'},
             'subfolder2': {'file1', 'file2', 'file3', 'file4'}},
 'folder3': {'file1', 'file2'},
 'folder4': {'subfolder1': {'file1', 'file2'}}}
```

Comment: As with the other solution, this assumes there are no mixed folders and subfolders so you get a crash on `[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'x', 'c']]`. I think OP needs to rethink their data structure.